# Problem with youtube: horizontally slow

Tags: debian, firefox, chrome, youtube

I have a problem with my Debian machine. I've installed it recently and there is a problem with  playing a youtube videos. It is like the bottom part is from previous frame. This happens on Firefox and Chromium. I tried h264ify plugins in both Firefox and Chromium. It might not seem like a big problem, but it is quite annoying. Probably it is answered somewhere, but I couldn't find it. Thanks for help.

[image: The problem]

Comment: Check if  the video driver was installed correctly

Comment: also what does lspci command gives

Comment: I have integrated graphics. i5 4570

Comment: I think thats your micro, run the lspci command to see the video device.

Comment: lspci: https://pastebin.com/jCRnW9cU

Comment: It seems your video card driver is fine It happens in youtube only or when you watch videos with a program from a local file?

Comment: It is only youtube issue. I didn't try any other online video services, but local videos are played well.

Comment: It also happens on stream.cz

Comment: try to update the flash plugin and the x264 from the deb manager you use (I dont use debian so do not recall if its apt or other utility)

Comment: Try to post the output of dmesg | tail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just solved it. I installed h264ify Firefox plugin AND x264 package from repository. I thought that h264ify has the codec included. Thanks riccs_0x.